# How to upload image from buffer with curl?

Tags: c, opencv, curl, raspberry-pi

I'm succesfully capturing frames with software described in [Pierre Raufast blog](http://thinkrpi.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/opencvpi-cam-step-6-video/).
I tried to upload image buffer using IplImage structures or raw buffer (please look at `buffer` and `dstImage` in `video_buffer_callback` function in this [source code](http://raufast.org/download/camcv_vid0.c)). I'm using modified code from libcurl [example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/postit2.html).

```
cvMatBuff = cvEncodeImage(".jpg", py, 0);
/* Fill in the file upload field from buffer */ 
curl_formadd(&formpost,
           &lastptr,
           CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "file",
           CURLFORM_BUFFER, "nowy.jpg",
           CURLFORM_BUFFERPTR, cvMatBuff,
           CURLFORM_END);
curl = curl_easy_init();
```

Unfortunately after execution I'm getting 500 error from my flask application.

```
192.168.0.16 - - [17/Nov/2013 21:02:22] "POST /faces HTTP/1.1" 500 -
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.0.16', 48537)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/usr/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 200, in handle
    rv = BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/usr/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 235, in handle_one_request
    return self.run_wsgi()
  File "/home/usr/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 194, in run_wsgi
    traceback.plaintext)
  File "/home/usr/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 71, in __get__
    value = self.func(obj)
  File "/home/usr/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/debug/tbtools.py", line 359, in plaintext
    return u'\n'.join(self.generate_plaintext_traceback())
  File "/home/usr/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/debug/tbtools.py", line 353, in generate_plaintext_traceback
    frame.function_name
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My server side code works fine when I'm uploading image from file by:

```
curl -F "file=@./medium.jpg" http://localhost:5000/faces
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you must explicitly pass the buffer length to libcurl with `CURLFORM_BUFFERLENGTH, len`.

Also I would recommend you to pass the content type with `CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, "image/jpeg"`

At last you must also take care to pass the *proper* buffer to libcurl.

`cvEncodeImage` returns a single-row matrix of type `CV_8UC1`. I don't know is there is any memory alignment with `cvEncodeImage` (?). So all you need to do is loop over the `cvMatBuff->data.ptr` array, and copy it row-by-row into a pre-allocated buffer of size `cvMatBuff->rows*cvMatBuff->cols` taking care to use `cvMatBuff->step` to skip to next row (stride).